# Bootstrap width thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, col

I want to use the thumbnails class to make a portfolio. But I have to change the width of the thumbnails div. And I have a problem with responsive because the `col-xs-12` property doesn't work because of my width modification. How can I fix this?

Here is the HTML :

```
<div class="row portfolio-items">
  <a href="http://patricechevalosteopathe.fr" target="_blank">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail patrice thumb-title">
        Patrice Cheval
      </div>
    </div><!-- End col-xs-12 -->
  </a>
  <a href="http://mariekbijoux.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail mariek thumb-title">
        Marie K Bijouterie
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-text">
        Test
      </div>
    </div><!-- End col-xs-12 -->
  </a>
  <a href="http://thibaultcheval.esy.es" target="_blank">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail thibault thumb-title">
        Thibault Cheval
      </div>
    </div><!-- End col-xs-12 -->
  </a>
</div><!-- End portfolio-items & row -->
```

And the CSS :

```
.portfolio-items{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.portfolio-items > a > div{
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #EBE7E4;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    left:3.3%;
}

.thumb-title{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#000;
    top: 63%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* compatibilité : ie9+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.thumb-title:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
.thumb-text{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:50%;
    color:#000;
    opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.thumb:hover > .thumb-title{    /* Hide the thumbname */
    top:20%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.thumb:hover > .thumb-text{    /* Show the thumb text */
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* compatibilité : ie9+ */
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `.portfolio-items > a > div{
    min-width: 20%; }`
try this

Comment: @KalpeshSingh -> Try this but don't working, it's same if I don't put a width property..

Comment: you don't need the col-xs-12 in the first place - at mobile (xs) size all undeclared widths are full width. Therefore you can just go with the sm and above. Not sure why you have an -sm offset but no col-sm -designation either.

Comment: Also - you are using Bootstrap to allow the use of the grid system but hen putting a width on it in the CSS which is what is throwing it out in the small viewports - you need to choose one approach and stick with it

Comment: I will change that so, thanks :)